# How to perform a query at specific time given php

Tags: php, mysql

Okay it is more like a suggest that how would I do.

I have a table that has products. What I am doing is that they have expiry date set like for instance `31-12-16` now if a user logs in then I can run a query at that time that any product that has expiry date less than current date will be marked as `disabled`. But this isn't appropriate solution. If user does not log in then products would not have marked `disabled` until he logs.

I was suggested to apply `cron-job`. But I don't know what it is.

Can anyone suggest how would I achieve this problem automatically? marking them disabled whether or not user logs in.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: @Dagon I have very less time and I have to learn cron-job from the scratch! Plus I have other projects to complete. I am here to get a suggest that is easiest and efficient. If you have a suggest please tell otherwise don't get bothered!

Comment: Cron jobs are really easy to learn. You just add a line to the file that says the command you want to run and the schedule for running it. The command is something like `php /path/to/script.php`.

Comment: @Barmar so script.php could be usual php script right?

Comment: Yes. It just can't use things like `$_POST`, since those come from the webserver client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a `MySQL event` that runs every day and updates the expired products to `disabled`.

**MySQL events**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE check_products()
BEGIN
// Place your update query here
// It is executed every day.
END $$
DELIMITER ; 


DELIMITER $$
CREATE 
    EVENT `disable_expired_products` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO BEGIN
    CALL check_products();
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Please take in mind MySQL events are disabled by default and need to be activated by placing `event_scheduler=1` inside `[mysqld]` of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

**Cronjob**

1. Go to your shell type crontab -e
2. Setup the cronjob, for example execution every night at 1:15 am

   `15 1 * * * php /home/user/update.php`

`update.php` has to fetch your rows, and update them according to your requirements.

A view on the table could be also useful, depending on your requirements.

Comment: This seems helpful, if can provide a short script for cronjob, there are many problems that would be solved for me!

Comment: I added to my answer how to setup a cronjob.

Comment: Oh God! This is easy! One last question. It wouldn't affect Mysql performance on the website right? It wouldn't slow it down?

Comment: That depends on your query and on the size of your database. In general it will not influence the performance.